Как сохранить название файла, не загружая сервер, без базы данных
Я получаю файл по id и его название, к примеру: id 1000, название filename.txt
Сохраняю файл на сервер по id (1000.txt), но название я не знаю как лучше сохранить.
Если бы было MySQL я бы сохранял туда название файла, но его нет…
Мои варианты очень тяжёлые для сервера:

Записывать во второй файл название файла и потом его читать (это засорять сервер файлами)

Этот вариант вроде бы лучше, записывать сразу 1000_filename.txt читать папку и с помощи массива находить по id, но он тоже будет нагружать сервера.


Может есть какой-то другой вариант менее нагруженные на сервера, так как файлов много, мои варианты не подходят.

Если хочется MySQL, а его нет - просто возьмите sqlite3, например?

Ну создайте папку по ID и там реальное название файла. Я не ПХПшник, но прочитать содержимое директории и вернуть первый - думаю не такая тяжелая операция и искать среди массива файлов ничего не надо

@SwaD ну вообще как ворочающий стопицот файлов заявляю - тяжёлая. А если почему-то нет SSD и файлы лежат на жёстком диске - то ОЧЕНЬ тяжёлая, и случайно может даже оказаться практичнее запихнуть файлы в тот же sqlite3. (Хотя критичность этого зависит от того, что конкретно автор собирается делать)

@andreymal
как вариант не плохой спасибо

В качестве БД для хранения названий файлов не обязательно иметь реляционную СУБД. Можно даже просто один или несколько текстовых файлов (в зависимости от кол-ва и набора необходимых данных помимо названий). Так же хочу напомнить, что не стоит хранить большое кол-во файлов в одном каталоге.

@andreymal Есть папка FILES. Там 100500 папок названных по ID файло(1000, 456, 234 и т.д.). В каждой папке гарантированно лежит только один файл. Обратится по пути FILES/1000/ и считать один единственный файл - ну это же быстрее и легче, чем читать все файлы. Верно ведь?

@SwaD
у меня файлов 2 миллиона, хоть я раскидал их по 30к на папку, думаю это будет нагрузка на файловую систему

@SwaD не факт, надо побенчить

Да не надо файлы в одну папку грузить. 1 файл в одной папке. папка названа по ID. Ну как бы я вариант без БД вижу такой, а там смотрите сами конечно.

@SeVlad
да, только когда txt файлом будут манипуляция, запись названий постоянно, то он может стать пустым и будет потеря всех названий, практика была. И все рано надо будет искать в txt название.

SwaD
Вариант прикольный, сделаю текст, что скажет файловая система :)

Если чтение файлов из каталога(листинг), хоть там и один файл, будет долгим, можно рассмотреть вариант туда допихать стандартный файл, допустим name.txt и там держать имя файла в текущей директории. по ID папки залезли в файл, прочитали, далее прочитали файл. Ну вдруг это будет быстрее, чем прочитать директорию с 1 файлом и взять 1й

@SwaD Да не надо файлы в одну папку грузить. 1 файл в одной папке. для файловой системы нет никакой разницы, папка на стопицот файлов или папка на стопицот подпапок с одним файлом каждая. Всё равно раком вставать. Для озвученных автором 2kk файлов самый разумный чанк - это 1-2 тысячи папок, плюс столько же файлов в каждой папке в среднем. Либо два уровня подкаталогов, по 100-200 подпапок/файлов на каждый.  ...

... При таком количестве файлов на папку дополнительный файл со списком уже не кажется сильно тяжёлым... Но нужна хорошая функция хэширования имён файлов, обеспечивающая достаточно равномерный разброс файлов по подпапкам. Иначе возникает необходимость в общем списке - для поиска, и тогда рушится вся затея. И да - я полностью согласен с предложением @andreymal об использовании SQLite.

@G-Force53 странные у тебя "отмазки". Конечно будут "манипуляции". Как иначе может быть осуществлена запись? И да, с файлами вне зависимости будет ли это полноценная БД, sqlite или простой тестовый файл. А насчёт пустого - надо просто грамотно писать чтобы такого не было. И это не зависит от способа хранения данных (только отличается нюансами). Ида, я просто предложил ещё одни вариант помимо предложенного ранее sqlite.
